# Find index of last character in string found with REGEX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I either need to find the length of a `MatchData` object, or the index of the last element in the string that is found. So I can insert another string after it.

The length of the found string is unknown as this code will run on many different websites.

I pull down a string (its a liquid template, and needs to remain liquid, cannot be converted to HTML, so Nokogiri is not an option)

The string I'm searching for is a form tag that could be any length, in this example it looks like this:

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart-wrapper">
```

I can also find the index of the FIRST element like this:

```
string.index(/\<form.*\>/)
```

I tried to use `rindex` but it returned the same value as `index`

I can just return the form tag like this:

```
found = string.match(/\<form.*\>/)
```

The above returns a `MatchData` object, but if I do this:

```
found.size
found.length
```

All it returns is `1`

My idea was to get the index of the `form` tag, then add the number of characters in the form tag itself, and then insert my string after that. But for some reason I can't find the index of the last character or the length of the `MatchData`.

Where did I go astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
last_index = str.index(/\<form.*\>/) + str[/\<form.*\>/].size
```

How does this work?

- `str.index` returns the starting index of the regex
- `str.[...]` returns the match itself
- `size` gets the length of the match

However,

It looks like you are manipulating an html string. Best use the `nokogiri` gem for that

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
form = doc.at('form')
form.inner_html = '<div>new content</div>' + form.inner_html 
puts doc
```

This appends new content inside the `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a string as follows.

```
def insert_str(str, regex, insert_str)
  idx = str.match(regex).end(0)
  return nil if idx.nil?
  str[0,idx]+insert_str+str[idx..-1]
end

str = '<form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart-wrapper">'
  #=> "<form action=\"/cart\" method=\"post\" novalidate class=\"cart-wrapper\">" 
insert_str(str, /\<form.*\>/, "cat")           
  #=> "<form action=\"/cart\" method=\"post\" novalidate class=\"cart-wrapper\">cat"
str
  #=> "<form action=\"/cart\" method=\"post\" novalidate class=\"cart-wrapper\">"

insert_str("How now, brown cow?", /\bbrown\b/, " or blue")
  #=> "How now, brown or blue cow?"
```

See [MatchData#end](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/MatchData.html#method-i-end). If you wish to mutate `str`, modify the method as follows.

```
def insert_str(str, regex, insert_str)
  idx = str.match(regex).end(0)
  return nil if idx.nil?
  str.insert(idx, insert_str)
end

str = '<form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart-wrapper">'
insert_str(str, /\<form.*\>/, "cat")           
  #=> "<form action=\"/cart\" method=\"post\" novalidate class=\"cart-wrapper\">cat"
str
  #=> "<form action=\"/cart\" method=\"post\" novalidate class=\"cart-wrapper\">cat"
```